Purpose of SYMBOL type STT_SECTION in ELF file in the Symbol Table
On the ELF format, in the symbol table there can be symbols that are type sections: STT_SECTION.
Every section can be identified by using the Section Header Table. What purpose does STT_SECTION serve? Is just a convenience or just a convention to have symbols as type STT_SECTION?

are you asking why since we have a section header table with information about the section in the .elf, we also need to define a type "SECTION"  in the symbol table?

Yes. I impression is its a duplication, but having it in the the symbol is a convention of some kind, or its there for some historical purpose.

I think the answer below explains it very well.

This can be useful for relocations. For example, you can put global variables in .data and reference them as .data + offset instead of creating relocations for each variable usage.
By doing so, you'll have a single relocation, that will put addr of .data to some register and all subsequent memory operations will be reg + known_offset.

Thanks totikom. Can you give me a concrete example please.

@shodz see this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Anchored-Addresses.html
